# Why can't I run my browsers in parallel on selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I have two very simple Cucumber feature files with identical scenarios of navigating to a page (currently both to the same webpage).

Feature_file_A:

```
Feature: Feature file A

Scenario: I want to navigate to a URL
  Given browser is opened and navigated to the URL "https://www.google.com"
```

Feature_file_B:

```
Feature: Feature file A

Scenario: I want to navigate to a URL
  Given browser is opened and navigated to the URL "https://www.google.com"
```

Then my step definition file looks like:

```java
public class StepDefs {
    @Given("Browser is opened and navigated to the URL {string}")
    public void browserIsOpenedAndNavigatedToTheURL(String url) {
        WebDriver driver = WebDriverFactory.createChromeDriver();
        driver.get(url);
    }
}
```

And `WebDriverFactory` looks like this

```java
public class WebDriverFactory {
    private static WebDriver driver;

    public static WebDriver createChromeDriver() {
        chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver();
        chromeDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        
        return chromeDriver
    }
}
```

The scenarios are run in parallel by having the following plugin added in `pom.xml`:

```xml
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <parallel>methods</parallel>
                    <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Then, I run the tests via `mvn test -Dtest=RunCucumberParallelTest`, whereby the test runner looks like this:

```java
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    glue = {
        "com.lastmile.supplychain.parallel.parallel_test"},
    features = "src/test/resources/parallel/parallel_test"
)
public class RunCucumberParallelTest {
}
```

The tests manage to run with two browsers showing, but only one browser navigates to the URL (in this case, google), and the other browser remains blank (it does not even attempt to navigate to the URL). Why is this the case?